# JSON string not in order

Tags: android

I want the JSON string to be in same order how I am putting it.This is my query.

```
object.put("name", name);
object.put("email", email);
object.put("query", query);
```

But in the resultant string its showing as

```
{"email""m@gmail.com","query":"k","name":"a"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of keys in a JS object is not guaranteed. If you need a particular order, consider having a separate array of keys to preserve the ordering.

```
{
  "order":["name", "email", "query"],
  "data":{
    "email":"m@gmail.com",
    "query":"k",
    "name":"a"
  }
}
```

From JSON specification http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt:

> An object is an ***unordered*** collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: It wont affect the php script?

Comment: If you change the format of the protocol, you definitely should also change the script on the other end of the communication channel.